# Difference Between Double's Notation

Tags: c++, double

On the learncpp.com there is advice to write doubles as:

```
double num {5.0}
```

Is there any real difference between that and:

```
double num {5}
```

It seems that my compiler (VS 2019) treats those as equivalent.

Comment: one is a floaing point double literal, one is an integer literal.

Comment: Those two lines do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that specific case, they are effectively equivalent, however, that's not always the case.

For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void foo(int v) {
  std::cout << "foo(int) called\n";
}

void foo(double v) {
  std::cout << "foo(double) called\n";
}

int main() {
  foo(5.0);
  foo(5);
}
```

That program produces:

```
foo(double) called
foo(int) called
```

If only for this reason, it's good to get into the habit of always using a `double` literal when you want to express a `double` value, even if an `int` literal would have worked just as well. Otherwise, sooner or later, you will run into some surprises.

Comment: Side note: When working with `float` expressions, you should use `5.0f`.